# Laravel 6.x When we enter wrong record from login then error doesn't showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Customization Multi-auth Panel system. Also without using `Auth::routes();`

When we enter the wrong record from login page then the error doesn't showing. Why?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input id="user_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('user_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="user_name" value="{{ old('user_name') }}" required autocomplete="user_name" autofocus>
        <label for="user_name">{{ __('User-Name') }}</label>
    </div>
    @error('user_name')
        <strong class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
        </strong>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: Please read that title and ask yourself if it is a good succinct description of the problem you're trying to solve. Then improve it.

Comment: please edit the question and be more specific. you might want to take us through the workflow to help us understand and help you